# Visualizing dependency tree depth in autofac

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I may have been searching for the wrong stuff, looking in the wrong boxes. But I can't seem to find a good way to visualize how deep my dependecy tree is in C#.

I've initially tried just hooking up on the preparing-event & the activating-event from Autofac. But I can't figure out if this is good enough. The results looks kinda funky. It seems that the preparing-event is initiated too often. And it seems that the activating event is only activated when a new object is actually created.

Our code is .NET 4.7.2
We're using Autofac as our container to handle the dependency injection.

Does anyone have a good idé for how we can visualize the depth? Maybe there exists some good code or a product out there that can help us?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some time ago, I had a similar quest with Autofac. What I ended up with was the following:

```cs
public class DebugResolveModule : Module
{
    private readonly ThreadLocal<ResolveInfo> _current = new ThreadLocal<ResolveInfo>();

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += Registration_Preparing;
        registration.Activating += Registration_Activating;

        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
    }

    private void Registration_Preparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        _current.Value = new ResolveInfo(e.Component.Activator.LimitType, _current.Value);
    }

    private void Registration_Activating(object sender, ActivatingEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        var current = _current.Value;
        current.MarkComponentAsResolved();
        _current.Value = current.Parent;

        if (current.Parent == null)
        {
            VisualizeGraph(current);
            Debug.WriteLine(
                $"total resolve time: {current.ResolveTime.TotalMilliseconds} ms.");
        }
    }

    private static void VisualizeGraph(ResolveInfo node, int depth = 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
        {
            Debug.Write("   ");
        }

        Debug.Write(node.ComponentType);
        Debug.Write(" (");
        Debug.Write(node.ResolveTime.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("F1"));
        Debug.Write(" ms. / ");
        Debug.Write(node.CreationTime.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("F1"));
        Debug.Write(" ms.)");


        Debug.WriteLine("");

        foreach (var dependency in node.Dependencies)
        {
            VisualizeGraph(dependency, depth + 1);
        }
    }

    private sealed class ResolveInfo
    {
        private Stopwatch _watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        public ResolveInfo(Type componentType, ResolveInfo parent)
        {
            ComponentType = componentType;
            Parent = parent;
            Dependencies = new List<ResolveInfo>(4);

            if (parent != null)
            {
                parent.Dependencies.Add(this);
            }
        }

        public Type ComponentType { get; }

        // Time it took to create the type including its dependencies
        public TimeSpan ResolveTime { get; private set; }

        // Time it took to create the type excluding its dependencies
        public TimeSpan CreationTime { get; private set; }
        public ResolveInfo Parent { get; }

        public List<ResolveInfo> Dependencies { get; }

        public void MarkComponentAsResolved()
        {
            ResolveTime = _watch.Elapsed;
            CreationTime = ResolveTime;

            foreach (var dependency in this.Dependencies)
            {
                CreationTime -= dependency.ResolveTime;
            }
                
            _watch = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Do note that this does not exactly what you want, because it is a resolve trigger. This means that a `SingleInstance` is only resolved once, which means the next time you request the graph, you'll be missing the singletons. This wasn't a problem for me, because I used this code to detect slow-resolving parts of the object graphs.

This code might, however, still give you some ideas of how to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a big step in the direction of where I wanted to go! :)

Comment: do you by any chance know why I'm getting my objects shows as being resolved multiple times? As an example, it looks like my controller is calling itself. The resolvetime is identical for each one, but the depth is not.

If you need more information I'll create a new question ;)

Comment: I'm sorry @Squazz, this has been some time ago that I used this code myself, but do note that when a component is registered as `InstancePerDependency`, it can get resolved multiple times in the same graph. But in case that dependency depends on `InstancePerLifetime` or `SingleInstance` dependencies, those dependencies won't be resolved twice in the graph. This means that (using this code), the first resolve of the `InstancePerDependency` dependency seems to have more dependencies than the next resolve, because this graph only shows resolves. Perhaps this is what's going on.

Comment: Noted. The scenario you are describing is different from what I see, so I created the following question ;) https://stackoverflow.com/q/59305813/