# How can/should I visualize autofac type or module regsitration in a UML diagram?

Tags: uml, autofac

More or less, what the title says.

I would like to visualize dependency injection (done by Autofac) in a UML class diagram.
Basically I am interested in showing that an Autofac Module (which is a class) register a type (another class), OR another autofac module (that might in turn register other types, or other modules).

What is the correct way of doing that?

Comment: Does it help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246792/visualizing-dependency-tree-depth-in-autofac ?